# Python, Pandas concat ladder

Tags: pandas, concatenation, tabula

I'm writing a pdf to xlsx converter for my work documents with tabula package.

I need to extract tables from all the pages from PDF and insert them into xlsx file.

i use **read_pdf** with "all" pages and get 1 page table with column names:

[image]

and all other pages have 1,2,3,4 column names:

[image]

So my problem is that when i try to concat all the pages, they turn into a stairs from the 2nd page, like this:

[image]

So how can i fix this, so every page will concat one by one, without moving to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the concatenation would work as you expect, if both dataframes would have the same column names. So the first thought is to rename the second dataframe like `df2.columns = df1.columns`. Then the concatenation should work. The problem here is that the columns of the second dataframe looks like valid data to me and this would be lost.

Here is a trick to save this line.

```
df2.loc[-1] = df2.columns
df2 = df2.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
df2.columns = df1.columns
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

This should do it.

**Example**

Here is a small example. I think this matches your problem.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[1,2,3,4]})
>>> df1
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1':[1,2,3,4], '2':[1,2,3,4]})
>>> df1
   1  2 # << valid data here
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
df2.loc[-1] = df2.columns
df2 = df2.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
df2.columns = df1.columns
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  4
4  1  2 # this data was saved
5  1  1
6  2  2
7  3  3
8  4  4
```

**Edit**

If you have a list of DataFrames, because of multiple pages, you can loop over this list:

```
# df_list = [df1, ... dfn]
for i, item in enumerate(df_list[1:], start=1):
    df_temp = item
    df_temp.loc[-1] = df_temp.columns
    df_temp = df_temp.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
    df_temp.columns = df_list[0].columns
    df_list[i] = df_temp

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: will this work, if i have not only 2 dataframes, but there could be more than 50, because each frame is a PDF page...

Comment: when i try to execute df2.loc[-1] i get KeyError: -1, because each index is a row

Comment: `df2.loc[-1]` raises an error, because the index `-1` does not exist. Your index starts at `0`.